# How does this creation of graph using stl library work?

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, stl

I have a doubt in a line given below of this code:

`cout<<"("<<c<<","<<(*i).get_vertex()<<") value of this pair : "<<(*i).get_weight()<<", ";`

How this get_vertex and get_weight work without the help of class edge object. The code compiled successfully and it's working too but I can't figure out how the above line is working.

Output of the code is:

```
 Pairs for 0 are -> (0,1) value of this pair : 2, (0,2) value of this pair : 3, (0,3) value of this pair : 4,
 Pairs for 1 are -> (1,2) value of this pair : 5, (1,0) value of this pair : 2,
 Pairs for 2 are -> (2,3) value of this pair : 8, (2,1) value of this pair : 5,
 Pairs for 3 are -> (3,0) value of this pair : 4, (3,2) value of this pair : 8,
```

Code is given below:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class edge{

  int weight,vertex;
  public:
    edge(int w , int v){
        weight = w;
        vertex = v;
    }

    int get_weight()const{
        return weight;
    }

    int get_vertex()const{
        return vertex;
    }


};


int main(){

    int n = 4;
    int c = 0;

    vector<list<edge>>adj(n) ;

    adj[0].push_back(edge(2,1));
    adj[0].push_back(edge(3,2));
    adj[0].push_back(edge(4,3));


    adj[1].push_back(edge(5,2));
    adj[1].push_back(edge(2,0));


    adj[2].push_back(edge(8,3));
    adj[2].push_back(edge(5,1));

    adj[3].push_back(edge(4,0));
    adj[3].push_back(edge(8,2));


    vector<list<edge>>:: iterator it ;

    for(it=adj.begin();it!=adj.end();it++){

        cout<<" Pairs for "<<c<<" are -> ";
        list<edge>li = *it;
        list<edge>::iterator i;
        for(i=li.begin();i!=li.end();i++){

            cout<<"("<<c<<","<<(*i).get_vertex()<<") value of this pair : "<<(*i).get_weight()<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        c++;
    }


}
```

Comment: i is an iterator, which is like a pointer into whatever is stored in your collection and when you dereference it, you a handle on the object, and in your case you have a list of edges, so gb (*I) is a reference to an edge object in the list

Comment: Ty  for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it into chunks.
Add whitespace:

```
cout << "(" 
     << c 
     << "," 
     << (*i).get_vertex() 
     << ") value of this pair : "
     << (*i).get_weight()
     << ", ";
```

Does that make more sense?

Comment: i have no problem with how it is wriiten i just wanna know how (*i) is accesing class edge member functions.

Comment: `i` is an iterator; which walks through the edges in the list `li`.  `*i` is the edge that `i` "points to"

Comment: Ty  i got my answer